# why package.json exports field not working in npm package

Tags: javascript, npm

I have developed an npm package that builds three js files.
in my project I want to import js files like this:

```
import MyButton from '@bslm/ui/MyButton'
```

so i used the **exports** field in my **package.json** like this:

```
"type": "module",
"exports": {
  "./MyButton": "./dist/my-button.common.js",
  "./MyInput": "./dist/my-input.common.js",
  "./MyImage": "./dist/my-image.common.js",
}
```

but when i try:

```
import MyButton from 'mypackage/MyButton'
```

I get this error: `These dependencies were not found`

node version: 14.18.1
npm version: 8.5.4

Answer (score -2):

Remove the leading '.'.  If you use './' as the keys you need to use objects like {"default":"./dist/my-button-common.js" } instead of a simple name.